# How to put and download the content of a div in html into pdf file using JS?

Tags: html, codeigniter, jspdf

I need to put the content of a div into a pdf file then download it. I've searched a bit and I found that you can use javascript to do this via [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf).

I found this sample code but it seems that it doesn't work for me. When I click the generate pdf button nothing happens. I am also using codeigniter for my framework and my website is currently uploaded in 000.webhost.com.

```
     <div id="content">
      <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

          <p>a pararaph</p>
     </div>
      <div id="editor"></div>
       <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>

         <script type="text/javascript">
       var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = { 
     '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
        };

       $('#cmd').click(function () {
              doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
         doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
     });

     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me on JSFiddle.net:
http://jsfiddle.net/scottcanoni/h3Lb05wa/

What error are you getting on your website?

All I am including is jQuery and the jsPDF script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://parall.ax/parallax/js/jspdf.js"></script>
```

If you include both jQuery and jsPDF in your `<head>` tag, you should be fine with the code provided.

Comment: there's no error. nothing happens when I click the generate pdf in my website. did you need to download the /parallax/js/jspdf.js ? I am a bit confused in where should I put jspdf js files in my document. I decided to put it together with my views. is that ok?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You need to include the jsPDF in between the `<head></head>` tags on your page.  Make sure it is there.  Alternatively, you can download the JS and serve it from your own domain.

Comment: yeah. I have included it. should the js files be in the same folder as the views? (using codeigniter as framework)

Comment: It doesn't have to be. It just has to be in the head tags. Find other JS files and put them there.

Comment: I've managed to make it work but I have a new problem. I can't seem to work it with the contents of a div that has tables.

Comment: it's output in the pdf file is like this

Copyright Pechay Productions 2014
ID
Type
Name
Owner
Contact #
Address
Accreditation Status
1
Apartment
Nicoles Apartment

It should be align horizontally.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what your new problem is and it seems like a new question.  You would need to post the HTML that you are trying to write to the PDF.  Make sure your HTML is validated and proper with no missing tags.  Simplify by removing HTML until it works then build up.  And if I helped, please upvote my comments and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JavaScript for a reason? I would (and have) use DOM PDF;

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf

Comment: could you create a simple code using the dom pdf? I can't understand it. I tried using the js because it's easy to understand and it is in the html file.