# Creating a pdf on button click from a html div containing multiple images with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I have a div containing four images, all of which are graphs created in a separate file. I am trying to allow the user to click a download PDF button that will create a PDF file with all four graphs via jsPDF.

As of right now all I am getting is a blank PDF page to download, none of the images show. If I add a header or paragraph tag in the div, that will show up, but non of the images will.

How can I show the images mentioned in the PDF?

I have tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362819/how-to-put-and-download-the-content-of-a-div-in-html-into-pdf-file-using-js)  and [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951936/jspdf-fromhtml-not-show-image) , but to no avail.

Here is my JS

```
$(function () {

  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
  };

  $('#downloadPDF').click(function () {
     var doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.fromHTML($('#tables').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
     });
     doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });
});
```

And the html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <div id="tables">
          <img src='vendors.png' alt='vendors'>
          <img src='positives.png' alt='positives'>
          <img src='total_submissions.png' alt='total submissions'>
          <img src='unique_submissions.png' alt='unique submissions'>
    </div>
    <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the the width of the image? and why are you specifying a width of 170 ?

Comment: The width of the image is 640px in the html, that didn't work so I tried using one of the examples I looked at